# Does "computer manipulated gibberish" have a name?

Tags: electronic-music

I'm referring to when, for example, in dubstep, you hear heavily edited voice samples, to the point where there are no recognizable words in it anymore.

Examples:

- [Kygo, Selena Gomez - It ain't me](https://youtu.be/D5drYkLiLI8?t=58s)
- [Skrillex - First of the year](https://youtu.be/TYYyMu3pzL4?t=13s)

Comment: I think it will be just called by the effects used to modify the voice (saturation, quantization, low-pass, reverbs... etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rhythmic cutting and splicing you hear in the first example is intended to resemble scatting or puard al thain (mouthing).  When this was first being done it was called cutting or chopping.  This method was first experimented with success by [Delia Derbyshire in the early 1960s back at the BBC Radiophonic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jetzY-W78gg).  In this example, Delia was using reversing and cutting of actual tape to make a sound that was distinctly alien.

Comment: Good answer.  It sounds like it might be related to [chopped and screwed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chopped_and_screwed) remixing.

Comment: so it's just called cutting or chopping? kind of dissapointing xD